# SSRS Pass multivalues parameter to sp_execute_external_script

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS reports  on sp_execute_external_script in R language.

I have problem with multivalues parameter.

@params = N'@age int'

I want choose from the report more values ?
example 3 , 5, 70 years old.
Thanks

Comment: Multi-valued parameters essentially pass your selections as a comma delimited string.  If you want to use more than one value in your query you will need to split your value list using a string splitter function

Comment: age  IN   (@years)     Do you think the IN is right? Thanks

Comment: No because you'll end up with `IN ('3, 5, 70')`.

Comment: @StevenWhite is correct within the context of passing multi value parameters to a stored procedure, but if you are using a Shared or Embedded Dataset, `in(@Param)` will actually provide the desired functionality.